# SQL OR condition to check duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql

Guys i need a small help. I need to check for duplicate entries in the database. I need to check either a duplicate phone entry or a duplicate email entry. Here's the sql. Is it correct? Because its not working.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
                ${$key}=addslashes($val);

                $contdupcheck = "select * from `contact` where `email` = '$email' OR `phone` = '$phone'";
                $contdupresult = mysql_query($contdupcheck);
                if(mysql_num_rows($contdupresult)==2)
                {
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">         
                    notification('You have already sent something twice!','error');
                    </script> 
                    <?php
                } 
                else 
                {

                    $contquery = "INSERT INTO `contact` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `message`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$contmessage')";
                    $contresult = mysql_query($contquery);
                    if($contresult)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">         
                        notification('Thank you for your message!','success');
                        </script>           
                        <?php
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">         
                        notification('There was an error. Please try after some time!','error');
                        </script>  
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: With just SQL and no background code, no one can help...

Comment: if your sql returns more than one record then dublicates are there.

Comment: have you set $email and $phone.and do not check for 2 instead make it 1.

Comment: @suchit - im allowing the user to send the message just twice

Comment: run the sql in php myadmin and see what you are getting.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Yes let me know how to do in one query

Answer (score 0):

> Just divide your query in two parts AS @suchit said

```
$contdupcheck = "select * from `contact` where `email` = '$email' OR `phone` = '$phone'";
   REPLACE IN TO

$contdupcheck = "select * from `contact` where `email` = '$email'";
$contdupcheck1 = "select * from `contact` where `phone` = '$phone'";
 $contdupresult = mysql_query($contdupcheck);
 $contdupresult1 = mysql_query($contdupcheck1);
AND NOW MATCH
 if(mysql_num_rows($contdupresult)==2 || mysql_num_rows($contdupresult1)==2)
```

Comment: @vinod - I know i can run two queries. I wanted if i can merge two in one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** it only going to produce desired out outcome if email and phone both are required. If they are optional let me know, i will update my answer. and yah you dont need to run two query for that. Thanks. if it does not work let me know.

```
$contdupcheck = "select * from `contact` where `email` = '$email' OR `phone` = '$phone'";
```

**change above line to this**

```
$contdupcheck = "select * from contact where email = '$email' AND phone = '$phone'";
```

---